# Multi threaded producer and consumer

Tags: java, multithreading, input, substring

I am trying to create a program that accepts information from the user and creates a file which contains information regarding a "fantasy team of game players." This is done by creating a string of 71 characters,
when the user enters "new" command it should ask for values to fill in the 71 characters:
(5+26+26+5+9)
5- ask for ID between 1-20 (Convert the ID to String) 
26- ask for players name 
26- ask for Team name 
5- ask for players skill level between 0 and 99 (convert Skill level to string)
9- Draft date (ex. 18May2013)

If a team name or date field is too short it should be filled in with blanks or if it is too long it should be cut off.
Then the record should be written at the record location indicatated by the ID. After this is done ask the user for a command again.

For the "old" command it should ask the user for the ID, index into the file and retrieve the record, DIsplay the record called back to the user. After this is done ask the user for a command again.

The "end" comand should simply close the program.

Here is my code so far I seem to be stuck on the "new" command specificly. I am stuck in the code where i need to make the string that 71 characters length (5+26+26+5+9) I believe i need to use .substring to make each input the correct length. Im not sure how to code this and how to deal with an input that is to long, optimally i would prefer to take the first correct amount as that strings section. Also how would i ask a user to input if an incorrect format was entered.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class Main{
    final private static int MAX_RECORD_NUMBER = 20;
    final private static int RECORD_LENGTH = 71;
    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
                        //throws NumberFormatException, NFException;
                        {
        File loc = new File("notepad.txt");
        RandomAccessFile store = new  RandomAccessFile(loc, "rw");
        String Dummy = "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"; //71 char for RECORD_LENGTH
        for (int i = 0; i< MAX_RECORD_NUMBER; ++i){
            {
                store.writeUTF(Dummy); //fill file with dummy records
            }
            String idNumber = "";
            String playerName = "";
            String playerTeam = "";
            String playerSkill = "";
            String draftDate = "";
            String record = "";
            int recLocation = 0;
            String where = "0";
            String cmd = "start";

            while (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end") != 0 )
            {
                cmd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input a command:'");
                if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("new") == 0 )
                {
                // Command is "new" - user wants to make a new record
                idNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input an ID Number between 1 and 20: ");    //5 char total

                playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input player's full name: ");             // 26 char total

                playerTeam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input player's team name: ");             //26 total char

                playerSkill = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input player skill level between 0 and 99: "); //5 char total

                draftDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the player draft date(Format 01Jan2014): "); //9 char total
                record = "" + idNumber + playerName + playerTeam + playerSkill + draftDate;
                assert record.length() == RECORD_LENGTH;
                if (recLocation == 0)
                {
                    recLocation = 1;
                }
                store.seek((RECORD_LENGTH+2) * (recLocation-1));
                store.writeUTF(record);
            }
            if  (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("old") == 0 )
            {
                //Command is "old" - user wants to see an existing record
                where = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input rec number");
                recLocation = Integer.parseInt(where);  
                store.seek((RECORD_LENGTH+2) * (recLocation-1));
                record = store.readUTF();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  record);
                }
            if (cmd.compareToIgnoreCase("end") == 0 )
            {
                //end command terminate program
            }
            }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your multithreading issue?